# Create a header file alias in cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I am converting some buck scripts to cmake and i have hit an issue where the script, based on conditional compilation flag creates an alias of the header file to include and in the source file the aliased named is included, for representational purposes we have  something like this

```
if(someConditionTrue)
Commheader.h = TargetAHeader.h
else
Commheader.h = TargetBHeader.h
```

I am wondering if something like this is possible with cmake. The file commheader.h doesn't exist in the file system and just is used as an alias to represent the necessary header.

I tried sset_source_files_properties and set_target_properties but it doesn't work , i still get filenotfound error when i compile the code.

PS: i am new to both buck and cmake,

Comment: There are several possible workarounds: 1) Use CMake to define a switch macro that you use in a wrapper header to choose which proper specific header to include. 2) Put the specific headers in different include directories and pick one to `target_include_directories` based on a CMake option variable. 3) Use CMake to do some symlink shennanigannery. The slightly more difficult part with those workarounds comes when you want to handle installation.

Comment: Hmm symlink seems to be platform dependent. probably target_include_directories would help.. will check it out.

Comment: CMake can create cross-platform symlinks. See the docs on [the `create_symlink` commandline command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-E-arg-create_symlink) (support added in 3.13). There is also [`file(CREATE_SYMLINK)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#create-link) for configure-time.

Comment: What compiler is this? How does it work _exactly_? I do not understand, I do not know any C preprocessor that allows to create file path aliases. `based on conditional compilation flag` What flag? `in the source file the aliased named is included` How is this possible _without_ CMake _exactly_? What compiler are you using?

Comment: Hmm i might have dig a bit deeper on this. its a build infra that we use for application binaries and it does this magic behind the scene. "based on conditional compilation flag" its a platform flag that we use which differentiates say between windows and linux OSs .

Answer (score 1):

What [@user](/users/11107541) wrote in the comments is the only reasonable way **from my experience**. Some time ago I had (not really the same, but similar) issue, that lead me to create either hardlinks if it was compiled on Windows or symlinks if it was elsewhere.

To distinguish it I checked for the compiler (we used only MSVC for Windows), i.e. I had code that looked something like this (inside a macro)

**NOTE:** in this example you can see it was `POST_BUILD` (hence why I mentioned it was only a similar problem):

```
    if (MSVC)

        # Make a hard link to the file
        add_custom_command(TARGET ${TARGET} POST_BUILD
            COMMAND if not exist "${HEADER_DEST_DIR}/${HEADER}" \( mklink /h "${HEADER_DEST_DIR}/${HEADER}" "${HEADER_SOURCE_DIR}/${HEADER}" \) 
        )

    else()

        # Make a symbolic link to the file
        add_custom_command(TARGET ${TARGET} POST_BUILD
            COMMAND ln -sf "${HEADER_SOURCE_DIR}/${HEADER}" "${HEADER_DEST_DIR}/${HEADER}"
        )

    endif()
```

I used `get_filename_component()` to get the required properties of the original headerfile example usage:

```
get_filename_component(HEADER_DIRECTORY "${HEADER}" DIRECTORY)
```

@user mentioned that it is much simpler now via `file(CREATE_SYMLINK)` and I would give it a try. Remember that you only need it for the build process.

Comment: Instead of using the `MSVC` variable, wouldn't it be better to use the [`WIN32`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/variable/WIN32.html) variable? Or am I missing something?

Comment: In our usecase (this macro is 2 years old) using `MSVC` was sufficient. I think with `WIN32` you might run into issues with `MSYS2`? But I'm not 100% sure about that. BTW this is just copy pasted from one of these old macros, hence it's more of an example rather than a concrete solution.

Comment: @MilanŠ. Thanks for the answer. I will try this out. Right now i am also trying to see if creating the header file itself instead of the alias will help in this.